# responsive image has different sizes on iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, image, responsive

I have an unreal problem with responsive images on smartphones...

On some iphones it is shown correctly on others it is shown very small. For example on iphone 6 from user A it is shown correctly on iphone 6 from user B it is shown too small.

Screenshots are attached, css code is here:

```
.bildresp figure img {
height: auto;
max-width: 1440px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing image on whole UI then use Auto-layout . Add UIImageView on your UIView with zero bounds and set Auto-layout for Trailing Space to super view , Leading space to super view, Bottom space to superview and Top space to Super view.

Comment: Which tool you are using to develop iPhone Application? Is it Xcode or something else? Because Xcode providing autosize class and auto layout for views.